# Delete temp files on startup

Tags: java, temp

My program requires a temp folder to put data in while running. This data is not needed after exit of the program and should be deleted. Each running instance of the program needs one folder on its own.

If I use `file.deleteOnExit()`, this does not make sure the file gets deleted on crash of whatever kind. My idea thus is to check for old temp files on startup that didn't got deleted and remove them. But when starting another instance of the program it shouldn't delete the temp files of still running programs. How can I achieve this?

To be more specific: The temp files should be in the System's temp directory and should be deleted if the program exits normally. This question is only for the few times the program crashed. The program has to be OS-independent. A solution using the `Path` instead of the `File` classes is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suggest to create at start for each application a private directory where store temporary files say `/var/run/myapp/tmp`.

And at start delete the directory content:

```
void purgeDirectory(File dir) {
    for (File file: dir.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) purgeDirectory(file);
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

You remain free to delete the directory content at app exit, but in this way, even if at the exit cleanup were not done correctly you're sure to have an empty dir at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is a bad idea to let your application to have multiple instances if you need to rely on other common resources, like temp file. For example, if you already have two instances of apps, the third one just opened will be hard to tell whether it is the third one and whether other instance is still alive.

As you have said, [deleteOnExit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()) will not clean temp file if JVM crash and Java doesn't provide a reliable way to clean temp file automatically.

So I have following suggestions:

- If you can choose to make only one instance of application with multiple windows:

  - You can have a fixed location and clean it when startup. But, in this way, you may give up some portability of Java.
  - If your application is GUI application, you can create temp file through Java API and register some clean action on closing the main frame, etc. -- still fail to handle some crash situations
  - you may add [shutdownHook](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) -- still fail to handle some crash situations
- If you insist on having multiple instances and your application is GUI application: have to use Java API to create temp file and may add listener or shutdownHook.

Comment: Due to the way the code is designed, it is impossible to make it run multiple instances from the same process in different windows like you suggested, even if this is a good idea.

Comment: @piegames As we have already discussed, there is no reliable way to delete temp file on exit, so we have to delete on startup. Having multiple instances will almost make this job impossible to do, as far as I know.

Comment: The program could put a timestamp in a file in the temp directory and update it every minute in a background thread. If the timestamp is older than ~5 min, the folder may be deleted by new instances.

Comment: @piegames I am curious that how to create those different temp directories if user open 100 instances?

Comment: Here's my attempt: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/160002/135603. I'm still testing it, but it looks good so far.